# Computing the characters of $\mathbf{1}_{D_n} \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}$

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters, dihedral-groups, young-tableaux

How can I compute the characters of the induced representation $\mathbf{1}_{D_n} \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}$?

Here, $S_n$ is the symmetric group over $n$ symbols and $D_n$ is the dihedral group of order $2 n$.

I can compute the character table of the symmetric group $S_n$ using the scheme mentioned in [this blog article](https://mathematicalgemstones.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/characters-of-the-symmetric-group/) which uses the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule.

Is there a similar approach for computing the characters of $\mathbf{1}_{D_n} \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}$?

I understand that I can compute the transversal of $D_n$ in $S_n$ and use it to compute the matrix representation of each element in $S_n$ as shown in the section 1.12 of [The Symmetric Group : Representations, Combinatorial Algorithms, and Symmetric Functions](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-6804-6) by Sagan. Then I can compute the characters by taking the traces. But this technique is tedious.

**Is there any shorter procedure where I can use the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule to compute the characters of $\mathbf{1}_{D_n} \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}$?**

---

**Motivation**

I am trying to detect the hidden subgroup $D_n$ of order $2 n$ within $S_n$ using [Normal Subgroup Reconstruction and Quantum Computation Using Group Representations](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~amnon/Papers/HRT.stoc00.pdf) as reference. This boils down to computing the Fourier transform of the following indicator function of a left coset of $D_n$ in $S_n$ which is assumed.

$$
f (g) =  \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{|D_n|}}       & \quad \text{ if } g \in c D_n\\
    0  & \quad \text{ otherwise}\\
  \end{cases}
$$
for some $c \in S_n$.

If the quantum Fourier transform is $\hat{f}$, we seek to measure the labels of irreps, $\rho$. According to the Lemma 1 in the paper, the probability of measuring $\rho$ is $\frac{|D_n|}{|S_n|} d_\rho \langle \chi_\rho, \chi_{\mathbf{1}_H}\rangle_{D_n}$.

Using a special case of Frobenius reciprocity as shown in the Lemma 2 in the paper, we can say that, $$\langle {\chi \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}}_{\mathbf{ 1}_{D_n}} , \chi_\rho \rangle_{S_n} = \langle \chi_{\mathbf{ 1}_{D_n}}, \chi_\rho \downarrow^{S_n}_{D_n} \rangle_{D_n}$$

That's why I need to compute $\langle {\chi \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}}_{\mathbf{ 1}_{D_n}} , \chi_\rho \rangle_{S_n}$. To do that I need to determine the character table of $\mathbf{1}_{D_n} \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}$.

Comment: So if that notation means "an induced representation," you're just looking for its (singular) character, and not *character table* right?

Comment: @pjs36, I am trying to compute the character table.

Comment: A "character table" is something associated to a group. What you're asking for the character table of is a representation (usually reducible) of $S_n$; it doesn't have a character table. The closest you could ask for is its decomposition into reducible characters (which, in general, is going to be fairly large; the order of $S_n$ grows as $n!$, while the order of $D_n$ grows as $2n$).

Comment: Or it occurs to me that perhaps you could want to decompose your induced character into irreducibles and hope that this gives enough of the characters of $S_n$ to fill in the rest of the table? If so, I don't think that's a very good approach due to the fact that the induced character will in general be of *huge* length. Young tableaux methods really are the best way to deal with representations of $S_n$.

Comment: @PL., I have appended my motivation to the body of the question.

Comment: @pjs36, I have appended my motivation to the body of the question.

Comment: Your edit does not address that the thing does not have a character table but a decomposition.

Comment: You appended your motivation (which I don't understand, btw) but the problem is that we don't understand **what** you are trying to do, independently of **why** you want to do it. As people have told you, representations do not have «character tables» so your question does not make sense at the moment.

Comment: But OK, while I'm not familiar with the language this is dressed up in (unfortunately, for some reason representation theory seems to come with a whole new set of names for objects in each application it finds), I think that this probably boils down to the following: given a representation $\rho$ of $S_n$, what is the multiplicity with which $\rho$ appears in $\mathbf{1}_{D_n} \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}$? For this, look up the formula for the character of an induced representation, and work it out. As I said though, there won't be a "nice" formula -- even for $n=10$ you'll have huge calculations.

Comment: @PL. , I was incorrect to attempt to compute the character table. It should be the characters of the induced representation.

Comment: @PL., I have fixed the question. Then following your comment, I have looked up the definition of the characters of induced representation at https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/characters-of-induced-representations/ . The expression is $$\chi \uparrow^G_H \left(g\right) = \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{x \in G} \chi \left(x^{-1} g x\right)$$ where, $H \le G$ . This expression is the induced character for a given group element. On the other hand, I need to determine ${\chi \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}}_{\mathbf{ 1}_{D_n}}$ where no group element is given. What should be my next step?

Comment: A character is a function. A function is determined by what it does to each element of its domain.

Comment: @PL., the inner product of characters is defined as follows. if $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are two characters of the group $G$, $$\langle \chi_1, \chi_2  \rangle = \chi_1 (g_1) \chi^\dagger_2 (g_1) + \chi_1 (g_2) \chi^\dagger_2 (g_2) + \ldots + \chi_1 (g_i) \chi^\dagger_2 (g_i) + \ldots + \chi_1 (g_n) \chi^\dagger_2 (g_n) $$, where $g_i \in G$.

Comment: @PL., So, $$\langle {\chi \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}}_{\mathbf{ 1}_{D_n}} , \chi_\rho \rangle_{S_n} = ({\chi \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}}_{\mathbf{ 1}_{D_n}} (g_1) \chi^\dagger_\rho (g_1) + {\chi \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}}_{\mathbf{ 1}_{D_n}} (g_2) \chi^\dagger_\rho (g_2) + \ldots +  {\chi \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}}_{\mathbf{ 1}_{D_n}} (g_i) \chi^\dagger_\rho (g_i) + \ldots + {\chi \uparrow^{S_n}_{D_n}}_{\mathbf{ 1}_{D_n}} (g_n) \chi^\dagger_\rho (g_n) )_{S_n}$$. Right?